# Velocity Vector Parallel To xy Plane

Tags: calculus

Particle moves by equations: $x\left(t\right)=5t^2,\:y\left(t\right)=10t,\:z\left(t\right)=5t^2-40t$

a) For what values of $t$ is the velocity vector parallel to the $xy$ plane

Attempt: When $ t=8$

b) When does the particle has minimum speed (i.e. at which point?)

Attempt:

$v(t) = <10t, 10, 10t, 40$

$|v(t)| =  $ $\sqrt{10t^2+10+10t-40}$

$|\frac{d}{dt}v\left(t\right)|\:=\:\frac{1}{2}\left(10t^2+10+10t-40\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 20t+10$

Comment: For $v(t)$, do you mean to write $10t - 40$ for the $z$ component?

Comment: i took the derivative of all three components.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what happened.  There's a typo in your $v(t)$.  You want a minus sign where you put a comma.

Comment: several-complex-variables, really?

Answer (score 0):

**Part A**:

It's hard to check your work with part A since you only gave an answer, but what you should've done is taken the dot product of the velocity vector with the normal vector to the $xy$-plane, which would be $\langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle$, and set it equal to $0$.  (Why will this give us what we want?)

Doing this, we get $\mathbf{v}(t) \cdot \langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle = 10t-40 = 0$

So, unless I've done something wrong, our answers come out to be off by a factor of $2$.

---

**Part B**:

Very helpful hint:  Minimize the *square* of the magnitude of the velocity vector instead.  You will get the same answer, but this will make it such that you don't have to deal with yucky square roots!  Also, in your work, it looks like you didn't square everything properly like you needed to.

At any rate, you should get:

$$v(t) = \langle 10t, 10, 10t-40 \rangle$$
$$|v(t)|^2 = 100t^2 + (10t-40)^2 + 100$$

And now I'll let you finish up with the usual process of setting the derivative equal to zero.